# Access 2016 I can't see Access Class Objects in VBE

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbe

I created tables and forms in Access 2016. When I Alt-F11 to VBE they do not show up. How do get them to show?

Answer (score 2):

Tables shouldn't be visible in the VBE at all. So that's expected. Only objects that have a VBA module are shown in the VBE.

Forms are only shown in the VBE if they have a module. Add a module to a form by opening it in design view, and either choosing *View Code* on the *Design* tab of the ribbon, setting the *Has Module* property to *Yes*, or by adding code to one of the events.